# How to Select Random 10 records in JPQL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have to select random 10 records from the user table,

Below is the SQL Query which gives random 10 records.

```
 SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
```

What is the JPQL alternative for this, Do we have Random() support for JPQL? is it a good practice to use RANDOM() ?

Comment: Why not consult a JPQL reference document for what functions are available? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether there is `RANDOM` in JPA. As an alternative solution you can use this trick :

```
Query queryCount = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM UserTable u");
Long size = (Long) queryCount.getSingleResult();

//I use this way of Java8, you can use the way you see it better to generate random indexes
int[] index = new Random().ints(0, size, 10).toArray();

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserTable u WHERE INDEX(u) IN :indexs");
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
query.setParameter("indexs", index);
List<UserTable> listUsersRandom = query.getResultList();
```

**Global idea**

This solution based on [INDEX](https://books.google.dz/books?id=Mh5KDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=select%20by%20index%20jpa&source=bl&ots=XO-STvnzaD&sig=u2KagzkA5qJOmocCJhOpqftx0vA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj08KCo9-TbAhUIbxQKHTOoCmsQ6AEIWTAE#v=onepage&q=select%20by%20index%20jpa&f=false). The idea is:

- First query - find the size of your objects
- Generate a list of index between 0 and the `size` of your list
- Second query - select the objects which is IN this generated list